# Setting translate3d independent of other transform

Tags: html, css, translate3d

I have a series of buttons with dynamic rotations:

```html
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="1" style="transform: rotateX(84.64deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 90px); transition-duration: 150ms;">1</button>
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="2" style="transform: rotateX(63.48deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 90px); transition-duration: 150ms;">2</button>
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="3" style="transform: rotateX(42.32deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 90px); transition-duration: 150ms;">3</button>
```

I want to change all their translateZ values, but adding this rule:

```css
.picker-opt { translate3d(0px, 0px, 100px) !important; }
```

also cancels out their `rotateX`, which is unacceptable.

I've enabled the Chrome Experimental Web Platform to get the independent `translate` but it doesn't appear to include `translate3d`! How silly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be indpendent then put the various tranforms on different elements.

```css
button {
 transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 90px);
 transition-duration: 150ms;
}
button:hover {
 transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<div style="transform: rotateX(84.64deg);">
  <button type="button" opt-index="1">1</button>
</div>
<div style="transform: rotateX(63.48deg);">
  <button type="button" opt-index="2">2</button>
</div>
<div style="transform: rotateX(42.32deg);">
  <button type="button" opt-index="3">3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use custom css :

```css
button {
  --var1 : 0;
  --var2 : 0;
  --var3 : 90px;
}
button:hover {
  --var3 : 100px
}


/* for demo purpose*/
html {height:100vh;display:flex;}
body {margin:auto;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="1" style="transform: rotateX(84.64deg) translate3d(var(--var1),var(--var2),var(--var3)); transition-duration: 150ms;">1</button>
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="2" style="transform: rotateX(63.48deg) translate3d(var(--var1),var(--var2),var(--var3)); transition-duration: 150ms;">2</button>
<button type="button" class="picker-opt" opt-index="3" style="transform: rotateX(42.32deg) translate3d(var(--var1),var(--var2),var(--var3)); transition-duration: 150ms;">3</button>
```

you can also set empty var with a defaut value :

```
var(--myVar, green)
```

```css
html {
  background: var(--myVar, green);/* green if  --myVar is not set */
  transition:0.15s
}

html:hover {
  --myVar: red; /* --myVar is now set */
}
```